# Remove and add multiple image in same UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am designing a make own pizza app. The user would add multiple toppings for example shrimp, bacon, and etc. on top of each other. So the adding image is working fine. Here is my code:

```
bool meatAdded;
- (void)addMeatTopping:(NSString*)meat  withImage:(UIImageView*)meatImage {
    if ((meatAdded =! meatAdded)) {
        //crust o taqir bede be cheese BADAN
        meatImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:_crustImage.bounds];
        [meatImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:meat]];
        [_crustImage addSubview:meatImage];

        for (UIButton*button in _meatButtonsArray) {
            checkMark.center = button.center;
            checkMark.alpha = 1;
        }

        [UIView animateWithDuration:.60 delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:.40 initialSpringVelocity:.20 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^ {
            meatImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.5, .5);
            meatImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);             } completion:nil];
    }else {
        /**** THIS PART OF CODE DOESN'T WORK ! IT PRINTS LOG BUT DOESN'T CHANGE THE MEAT IMAGE AT ALL ****/

        NSLog(@"Remove");
        meatImage.alpha = 0;
        [meatImage setImage:nil];
        [meatImage removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

example of calling above method:

```
- (IBAction)meat0:(id)sender {
    [self addMeatTopping:@"topping_Bacon" withImage:beykenMeat];
}

- (IBAction)meat1:(id)sender {
   [self addMeatTopping:@"Steak" withImage:steykMeat];
}
```

How can I create a toggle method when user select an item? The item will add to view and when taps again it should be removed from view.

Comment: why dont you load the previous image again, instead of undoing ?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this `if` statement? `if ((meatAdded =! meatAdded))`. I doubt that is what you actually want since that negates `meatAdded` and then assigns the new value to `meatAdded` and then finally checks to see if the new value is true or false.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri : there is no previous image. It adds by user step by step First crust -  sauce - cheese (there are single choice) then meat , vegetables (these are multiple choice)

Comment: Change the log to `NSLog(@"Remove:%@", meatImage)`-- did `meatImage` somehow become `nil` somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

```
SubclassImageView *imageviewG = [[SubclassImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
self.crustImage = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 250, 250)];
self.crustImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[imageviewG setImage:@"topping_Bacon"];

[self.crustImage addSubview:imageviewG];
[self.view addSubview:self.crustImage];

    for(id viewInner in self.crustImage.subviews){
    if([viewInner isKindOfClass:[SubclassImageView class]]){
        SubclassImageView *imageSeleted = (SubclassImageView *)viewInner;
        if([imageSeleted.getImageName isEqualToString:@"topping_Bacon"]){
        //your logic to add or remove the imageview from super view
        }else if([imageSeleted.getImageName isEqualToString:@"Steak"]){
        //your logic to add or remove the imageview from super view
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: //SubclassImageView is subclass os UIimageView

-(void) setImage:(NSString*)fileName
{
    imageFileName = fileName;
    [super setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:fileName]];
}
-(NSString*) getImageName{
    return imageFileName;
}